# Why are there kids at the SHIELD Dark Energy Research Facility?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012

In the *The Avengers* (2012), we see that there’s an event going on that results in the facility being evacuated. During the Evacuation process we see what look like kids in pajamas being led out of the facility.
Why were they there to begin with? If this was a secret research area in the middle of nowhere, wouldn’t the researchers be flown in and out, similar to how Area 51 used to work?

[image: Kids evacuating the SHIELD Dark Energy Research Facility]

Comment: There is real life presence. For example, [some children lived near the Manhattan Project facility with their parents](https://www.atomicheritage.org/article/children-manhattan-project).

Comment: Because there are laws against testing on guinea pigs....